# Prove that $f_*: H_2(T; \mathbb{Z}/2)\to H_2(K; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ is the trivial mapping.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

**Let us denote by $T$ the torus and $K$ the bottle of Klein. Let $f:T\to K$ be a continuous function. Prove that $f_*: H_2(T; \mathbb{Z}/2)\to H_2(K; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ is the trivial mapping.**

I know that $H_2(T; \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $H_2(K; \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$, but I don't know how to conclude that $f_*$ is trivial, could someone please help me or give me a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by looking at a certain commutative square:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_2(T)@>{f_*}>> H_2(K)\\
@VVV @VVV  \\
H_2(T;\mathbb{Z}_2) @>{f_*}>> H_2(K;\mathbb{Z}_2)
\end{CD}$$

This is evidently commutative since taking a chain and reducing its coefficients mod 2 commutes with taking a chain and pushing it to a chain in the Klein bottle.

The first vertical map is surjective by the universal coefficient theorem since tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the same as reducing coefficients mod 2. The second vertical map is 0 since $H_2(K)=0$. This means that the lower horizontal map must be 0, as claimed.

Comment: I understand almost everything you say, unless the diagram you put is commutative, why is this true? How could I prove that the diagram commutes formally? Thank you.

Comment: To prove the diagram commutes you should verify what I said by writing out the maps.

Comment: Suppose $\phi: H_2(T)\to H_2(T;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ and $\xi: H_2(K)\to H_2(K;\mathbb{Z}/2)$, in this case I would have to prove that $f_*\phi=\xi f_*$, but $\xi$ is equal to zero because $H_2(K)=0$ so I get to $\xi f=0$, what else can I do?

Comment: This is not something unique to these spaces. This commutative diagram works for any spaces, maps, degrees, and quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$ even prior to taking homology. Zoom out rather than in.